# Advance Ajax Loader Plugin wordpress Google map not loading

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I use `Advance Ajax loader wordpress plugin`.

I use `function` to load `google map` but when i switch from one page to other page using `ajax` the map does not load.

How ever i tried my function in reload code of advacnce ajax loader in backend but nothing works for me the map does not load

Comment: I resolved it if any one facing this issue just use iframe and place inside page the map function will load easily with ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it if any one facing this issue just use iframe and place inside page the map function will load easily with ajax